# Slow Mongo queries from Rails app taking > 1000 ms ... ideas for optimization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

We built a Rails app on Mongo 2.2 and Rails 3.2.12. We're new to Mongo and would appreciate any tips on how we should optimize very slow queries, ones that take longer than 1000 ms.

We're using MongoMapper as the interface to Mongo.

We are indexing these table, but is there a way to confirm whether our queries are using these indices properly? How else can we pinpoint the cause of slowness?

Here is one day's worth of slow Mongo queries: https://gist.github.com/panabee/2876e833002f3151eeda

Here is explain on three of those queries: https://gist.github.com/panabee/358bd87ba7b954018dab

Comment: How does one "index a query"?

Comment: Sorry, meant indexed the tables. :)

Comment: How else can we pinpoint the cause of slowness?
1st and 3rd query is using $ne, $nin, which are not index friendly,  causing nscanned, nscannedObjects to be very high. The 2nd query is "$in" which will be very fast. So you have to get some key in the 1st and 3rd query, which will be specific just like in the 2nd query.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#query-operations-that-cannot-use-indexes-effectively 
 what information do you want from me ?

Comment: would just like to ask a quick question about mongo, @AbhishekKumar. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is schema design, indexing design and probably also insufficient resources to handle the current load (possibly - it's impossible to tell without fixing the queries first).

When designing your schema you must consider how you will be accessing the data for reads and writes.  The structure of your documents and your indexing strategy must reflect the needs of the reads and writes.  You currently have queries which must scan thousands of documents to select very few - this is a reflection of poor indexing strategy.  With effective indexing your queries should be able to use indexes to zero in on the number of documents they need, in addition if sorts must be done then those should also be supported by indexes.

This would not be appropriate venue for an answer since your problem isn't that you are missing a single index or using the wrong type of query.  You need to reconsider your schema design and your indexing strategy based on the needs of your application.

Comment: thanks @asyakamsky. we designed the schema with read & write profiles in mind. this is why we embedded games in the player document -- because we typically access both at the same time, and we were told that as long as the games array (which only contains object ids) doesn't expand beyond 1000 items or so, it was sound architecture. is it possible to index a timestamp? the slow queries are finding players who have done something with the last few hours or so. or is it better to put these active players into a separate collection and scan that separate collection (which you seem to suggest)?

Comment: it's certainly possible to index a timestamp but don't forget you need a compound index to narrow the results of query efficiently. Are you continuously pushing new games to players arrays?  If so that's very poor design as the document will keep growing and every time it's relocated on disk it will cause fragmentation plus all the indexes have to be updated, making for poor update performance.

Comment: Also you are filtering by timestamp but sorting by _id, why?  Anyway this is not a good forum for this discussion - consider posting this on the MongoDB-users Google Group.

Comment: we are pushing new game IDs -- but not games themselves, precisely to avoid fragmentation. is this not the recommended practice for something like a game?

Comment: Growing arrays are bad especially if they are unbounded, and indexed.

Comment: Are you only keeping current games or all games?

Comment: Current games. More specifically, we're only keeping game IDs in the player collection. We were told fragmentation wouldn't be an issue with embedding game IDs. Games are stored in their own collection. Mongo stats: https://gist.github.com/panabee/1ece342e8b5b95040ac3. Our performance issue is fetching games with this query: "Game.find ids", where "ids" represents an array of game IDs. These queries often take > 100 ms. Any help you could offer would be awesome. This is very frustrating!

Comment: you should take this discussion over to the google groups mongodb-users.  that's a more appropriate venue for this type of lengthy discussions, plus it's easier format than comments on SO.

Comment: google groups post, btw: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/w0nvuD0Zzdc